# GenericWildcard is not applicable

Tags: java, generics

I have a function

```
public static void bar (final List<List<?>> list)
{
}
```

which I can call with a wildcard (`<?>`)

```
bar(new ArrayList<List<?>>());
```

but not with another type (e.g. `String`)

```
// The method bar(List<List<?>>) in the type Foo is not
// applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<List<String>>)
bar(new ArrayList<List<String>>());
```

However this works for the similar function

```
public static void foo(List<?> l)
{
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // no error
    foo(new ArrayList<String>());
}
```

Can you please explain, why the compiler complains in the first case but not in the second?

Answer (score 4):

You should declare your method as:

```
private void bar(final List<? extends List<?>> lists) {...}
```

In this case the call `bar(new ArrayList<List<String>>());` would work.

### The explanation

In short:

`List<SomeType>` - The compiler will expect a call with **exactly** the same type.
`List<? extends SomeType>` - The compiler will expect a call with a class that is a compatible (sublass) with `SomeType`.

In your case a definition

```
void bar (final List<List<?>> list)
```

will expect a parameter whose definition is exactly `List<List<?>>() nestedList;`

On the other hand, when you specify your method as:

```
void bar(final List<? extends List<?>> lists)
```

Then you're saying that you have a list whose types are upper-bounded by `List<?>`, so `ArrayList<String>` would be a valid candidate for the nested list

From [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html):

> There is a small but very important difference here: we have replaced
>   the type List with List. Now drawAll() will
>   accept lists of any subclass of Shape, so we can now call it on a
>   List if we want.
>
> List is an example of a bounded wildcard. The ?
>   stands for an unknown type, just like the wildcards we saw earlier.
>   However, in this case, we know that this unknown type is in fact a
>   subtype of Shape. (Note: It could be Shape itself, or some subclass;
>   it need not literally extend Shape.) We say that Shape is the upper
>   bound of the wildcard.

Comment: It's not the question HOW he should do it, but WHY it does not work!

Comment: Updated with explanation... remove downvote?